# Why error login and password server return status 200 ok

Tags: authentication, server, status

All major web applications (Google, Facebook, etc.) return page status `200 ok` in case of authentication failure, i.e. wrong login/password pair.

Although by [definition](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), if a resource is not found with request URI - status `404 Not found` is returned.

Wikipedia says:

> [404 Not Found] Used when the requested resource is not found, whether it doesn't exist or if there was a 401 or 403 that, for security reasons, the service wants to mask

How does the *login* case differ?

Comment: This is a broad question.

Comment: Did anyone managed to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Server code 200 means you get the response . Whether it is your wrong credentials or not. if Your request has not been processed then server returns different error code . But for your case,

Your login request has been processed , connection with database has been established and from that you get you wrong credential message . So code 200 is for your successfully processed request.

Comment: `200 ok` does not just mean one gets a response, but rather that the latter is successful and the requested resource is returned (i.e. a sesson in this case). The only case with no server response is statuses like `504 Timeout`

Comment: he is talking 'bout login error means credentials isn't correct  . @OlegAfanasyev